# Creating best pie chart layout using optional arrows

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, pie-chart

I'm just wondering about one idea of creating proper layout for pie chart. Have a look at code following :

```
library(ggplot2)


pie_chart=function(vec){
  if (class(vec)=='numeric'){vec<-as.character(vec)
  vec<-print(paste('var',vec))
  }
  #creating data frame : variables and number of their occurrences
  df<-data.frame(table(vec))
  colnames(df)[1]<-'group'
  #creating bar plot first
  bp<- ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=Freq, fill=group))+
    geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity")
  blank_theme <- theme_minimal()+
    theme(
      axis.title.x = element_blank(),
      axis.title.y = element_blank(),
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      panel.grid=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      plot.title=element_text(size=14, face="bold")
    )
  #adding polar coordinates to make a circle
  pie <- bp + coord_polar("y", start=0)
  pie + scale_fill_brewer("Characteristic") + blank_theme +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())+
    geom_text(aes(y = rev(Freq)/2 + c(0, cumsum(rev(Freq))[-length(Freq)]),
                  label = print(paste0(rev(Freq),'(',percent(rev(Freq)/(sum(Freq))),')'))), size=5)
  
}



pie_chart(c(rep(1,40),rep(2,30),rep(3,90),rep(8,2)))
```

[image]

As you can see, number '2(1.2%)' above is dominated by other numbers which significantly has bad presence influence on our pie chart. I want to change my function in such way that if some value is less than 5% of all pie, this value should be outside the pie with arrow leading to proper part of pie with other values unchanged (inside the pie).

So in our example '2(1.2%)' should not be in pie, but outside the pie with arrow leading to the upper side of pie. Do you have any idea how it could be done ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution that places the text label outside the x-axis limits by using `scales::oob_keep()` and turning off the coordinate clipping. You can control the looks of the arrow with the `arrow()` function.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

pie_chart=function(vec){
  if (class(vec)=='numeric'){vec<-as.character(vec)
  vec<-print(paste('var',vec))
  }
  #creating data frame : variables and number of their occurrences
  df<-data.frame(table(vec))
  colnames(df)[1]<-'group'
  #creating bar plot first
  bp<- ggplot(df, aes(x=1, y=Freq, fill=group))+
    geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity")
  blank_theme <- theme_minimal()+
    theme(
      axis.title.x = element_blank(),
      axis.title.y = element_blank(),
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      panel.grid=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      axis.text = element_blank(),
      plot.title=element_text(size=14, face="bold")
    )
  #adding polar coordinates to make a circle
  pie <- bp + coord_polar("y", start=0, clip = "off")
  pie + scale_fill_brewer("Characteristic") + blank_theme +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())+
    geom_text(aes(y = rev(Freq)/2 + c(0, cumsum(rev(Freq))[-length(Freq)]),
                  label = print(paste0(rev(Freq),'(',percent(rev(Freq)/(sum(Freq))),')')),
                  x = ifelse(rev(Freq) / sum(Freq) < 0.05, 1.7, 1)), 
              size=5) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = 1.6, xend = 1.5, 
                     y = rev(Freq)/2 + c(0, cumsum(rev(Freq))[-length(Freq)]),
                     yend = after_stat(y),
                     colour = I(ifelse(rev(Freq) / sum(Freq) < 0.05, "black", "transparent"))),
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(1, "mm"))) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.5, 1.5), oob = scales::oob_keep)
  
}

pie_chart(c(rep(1,40),rep(2,30),rep(3,90),rep(8,2)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>